# The "text_plain" plugin does not exist

Tags: migrations

I'm a member of a student group. A couple of years ago some former members build a knowledge management system on top of Drupal 7. It worked great since then but know we want to migrate to Drupal 8.

I cloned the existing Drupal 7 to a new VM and installed a Drupal 8 instance alongside. I then used the web based migrate tool. As expected, I ran in a lot of errors and are now working my way trough them.

One Error where I got stuck is the one mentioned in the title. The whole error message is:

> The "text_plain" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for
>   Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterPluginManager are: comment_username,
>   comment_default, comment_permalink, datetime_default,
>   datetime_time_ago, datetime_custom, datetime_plain, file_link,
>   file_table, file_extension, file_size, file_url_plain, file_filemime,
>   file_default, file_uri, file_audio, file_video, file_rss_enclosure,
>   image_url, image, link_separate, link, list_default, list_key,
>   entity_reference_rss_category, text_default, text_trimmed,
>   text_summary_or_trimmed, author, user_name, basic_string,
>   email_mailto, timestamp, number_unformatted, language, boolean,
>   entity_reference_label, number_integer, string,
>   entity_reference_entity_view, uri_link, timestamp_ago,
>   entity_reference_entity_id, number_decimal
>   (/var/[...]/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php:53)

I started looking around and found this issue: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3042223
Form what i understand, this should solve my problem. However, I am already using 8.7.4 and according to the release notes, it should contain the patch. To confirm that, i looked into the sources of my installation and the patch is definitely installed.

What could i do to solve this issue? I am thankful for every hint.

Comment: You 100% sure the patch is in? The issue relates to the 8.7.x-dev branch. And the issue is just "fixed" not "closed" yet. Which normally means it not released yet.

Comment: According to the Changelog[1] its in and when i look at my drupal installation in the respective php file the line is there:

```case 'string':
        $formatter_type = str_replace(['text_default', 'text_plain'], 'string', $formatter_type);
        break;````

[1]:https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.7.4